# right uiBarButtonItems pushes my titleview to the left

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I added two uibarbuttonitems to the right but it pushes the titleview to the left.

I want the titleview to stay centered and truncated if its too long

Comment: Please add the iOS tag to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method below will do just that: **stay centered** + **truncate** if it is too long.

Add an equal number of fixed spaces (2 in your case) to the left. It may require you to:

1. replace the leftmost `UIBarButtonItem`
2. use `navigationItem.titleView` (which you already are) : add an equal number of `UIBarButtonItem` and `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace` to the left.

**Note**: To achieve perfect centering, use a width of **21.5** to be rigorous, **22.0** to be conservative:

```
// Adding invisible spaces to the left
UIBarButtonItem * space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
    target:nil action:nil];
space.width = 21.5; // Exact match
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:@[space,space]];
```

Just for reference, the title view should look like this:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = ({
    UILabel * titleView = [[UILabel alloc]
        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)];
    [titleView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

    titleView;
});
```